# 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 61-61

Tags: python, json, unicode, encode

When I run my Python code and print(item), I get the following errors:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 61-61: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Here is my code:

```
def getUserFollowers(self, usernameId, maxid = ''):
    if maxid == '':
        return self.SendRequest('friendships/'+ str(usernameId) +'/followers/?rank_token='+ self.rank_token,l=2)
    else:
        return self.SendRequest('friendships/'+ str(usernameId) +'/followers/?rank_token='+ self.rank_token + '&max_id='+ str(maxid))
def getTotalFollowers(self,usernameId):
    followers = []
    next_max_id = ''
    while 1:
        self.getUserFollowers(usernameId,next_max_id)
        temp = self.LastJson

        for item in temp["users"]:
            print(item)
            followers.append(item)

        if temp["big_list"] == False:
            return followers            
        next_max_id = temp["next_max_id"]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: On which line does the error occur, what is `followers`, and what is `temp["users"]`?

Comment: followers is a list ,and temp is  josn Loaded content where self.LastJson = json.loads(response.text).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to guess without knowing the content of `temp["users"]`, but the error indicates that it contains non BMP unicode characters like for example [emoji](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

If you try to display that in IDLE, you immediately get that kind of error. Simple example to reproduce (on IDLE for Python 3.5):

```
>>> t = "ab \U0001F600 cd"
>>> print(t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print(t)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 3-3: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

(`\U0001F600` represents the unicode character U+1F600 *grinning face*)

The error is indeed caused by Tk not supporting unicode characters with code greater than FFFF. A simple workaround is the filter them out of your string:

```
def BMP(s):
    return "".join((i if ord(i) < 10000 else '\ufffd' for i in s))
```

`'\ufffd'` is the Python representation for the unicode U+FFFD *REPLACEMENT CHARACTER*.

My example becomes:

```
>>> t = "ab \U0001F600 cd"
>>> print(BMP(t))
ab � cd
```

So your code would become:

```
for item in temp["users"]:
    print(BMP(item))
    followers.append(item)
```